# Is there anything wrong in the wording of this question?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\phi:R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism, and $I$ an ideal of $R$. Define $\phi(I) := \{\phi(a)|a \in I\}.$ Show that $\phi(I)$ is an ideal of $S.$ If $\phi$ is an isomorphism, prove $\frac{R}{I} \cong \frac{S}{\phi(I)}.$

A friend told me that the phrase "be a ring homomorphism" should be "be a ring isomorphism" and consequently, the phrase "If $\phi$ is an isomorphism" should be omitted.

But I don't see why??

Comment: The image of an ideal is not necessarily an ideal in general. For example, the inclusion map $\phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ carries the ideal $2\mathbb Z$ to $2 \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$, which is not an ideal in $\mathbb Q$. It is sufficient to assume that $\phi$ is surjective, for both claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\phi(I)$, as you've defined it, is not necessarily an ideal.  If $\phi$ is surjective then it's necessarily an ideal so, in particular, if $\phi$ is an isomorphism then indeed $\phi(I)$ is an ideal.